# How do I properly seed data with a circular dependency in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

First of all, I am using Entity Framework Core (in .NET Core 3.1) with the code-first approach.

Imagine I have a couple of entities like this:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Department))]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Manager))]
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
}
```

With the semantics that every `Employee` belongs to a `Department` and every `Department` has an `Employee` as a manager.

I would like to seed the database with some values, say the *"CEO"* of the company that will belong to a *"Direction"* department of which he should be the manager; however when I try to perform this I am faced with an error.

**Is there anything I can do to insert both an `Employee` and a `Department` at the same time while seeding the database using an instance of `ModelBuilder`?** I know there is a way to disable the foreign key constraints but since this is code first, I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly unrelated to whether you're adding data in seeding or not.  SaveChanges will throw an exception if it can't apply the requested changes in a sequence of INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.  Here if you add a new Department and Manager where the Manager is in the Department and is its Manager, neither entity can be INSERTED.

Normally you would simply make it optional for the Department to have a Manager.  After all, what happens if a Department's manager quits?  It makes sense that the Department might have no manager for a while, even after it's created.  So Add the new Department, SaveChanges(), Add the new Manger to the department, SaveChanges().

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I ended up modifying my model. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I have a similar situation where I have a User entity which has an owner, i.e. a Person Entity. All entities have a createdBy which is a foriegn key reference to a User entity, including the User itself. I don't want any to be null as in my Domain a User can't exist without being owned by a person. How can I seed this model with the first User and Person via the modelBuilder HasData method?

Comment: That should work fine.  Try it, and if you have trouble post your Entity design in a new question.